# Optimize Query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-performance

I've following tables with respective fields

```
1) wi_individual_g(ind_id,ind_is_recepient,ind_deleted,ind_district_id,...) - Around 200K data
2) wi_individual_p(ind_id,prg_id,...) Around 250K data
3) wi_training(trn_id,trn_start_date,trn_deleted,trn_beneficiary_type,...) - Around 25K data
4) wi_indv_training(ind_id,trn_id,is_deleted) - Around 450K data
5) wi_district(dst_id,dst_name) - Around 75 data
```

I was required to define a query to report unique individuals who are participated in the training within the given ranges of training dates (dst_name wise). So, I created following QUERY to fetch the records

```
SELECT 
wi_district.dst_name,
COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE
        WHEN wi_training.trn_start_date BETWEEN '2014-07-01' AND '2015-06-30' THEN wi_individual_g.ind_id
    END)) AS y3,
COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE
        WHEN wi_training.trn_start_date BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2014-06-30' THEN wi_individual_g.ind_id
    END)) AS y2,
COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE
        WHEN wi_training.trn_start_date BETWEEN '2013-02-01' AND '2013-06-30' THEN wi_individual_g.ind_id
    END)) AS y1
FROM
wi_individual_g
    INNER JOIN
wi_individual_p ON wi_individual_p.ind_id = wi_individual_g.ind_id
    AND wi_individual_g.ind_is_recepient = 'yes'
    INNER JOIN
wi_district ON wi_district.dst_id = wi_individual_g.ind_district_id
    AND wi_individual_g.ind_deleted = 0
    INNER JOIN
wi_indv_training ON wi_indv_training.ind_id = wi_individual_g.ind_id
    AND wi_indv_training.is_deleted = 0
    INNER JOIN
wi_training ON wi_training.trn_id = wi_indv_training.trn_id
    AND wi_training.trn_deleted = 0
    AND wi_training.trn_beneficiary_type = 2
    AND wi_training.trn_start_date <= '2015-06-30'
GROUP BY wi_district.dst_name
```

The INDEX has been applied to every fields on ON-CLAUSE and AND-CLAUSE. This query is taking around 4 mins to execute and fetch the records. How can I apply other optimizations to the present query? Please provide me some solutions in MySQL!

The EXPLAIN for the above QUERY is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> The INDEX has been applied to every fields on ON-CLAUSE and AND-CLAUSE.

Please learn about "compound indexes".

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

```
AND wi_training.trn_deleted = 0
AND wi_training.trn_beneficiary_type = 2
AND wi_training.trn_start_date <= '2015-06-30'
```

Begs for the compound `INDEX(trn_beneficiary_type, trn_deleted, trn_start_date)`.

A compound index is almost always better than `Using intersect(...)`.

(Style recommendation:  Don't prefix all columns with the same thing; it unnecessarily clutters the SQL.)

Comment: I've added the EXPLAIN SELECT result for the query. Thank you!

Comment: And have you tried the index I suggest?  (I did an edit, too)

Comment: If many of the rows are "deleted", then performance is being hurt by `AND wi_...._deleted = 0`

Comment: Yes! I've tried implementing COMPOUND INDEX as you've suggested. Its taking 3.3min on localhost(windows+chrome). Even simple query with all table JOINs taking a lot of time..

Comment: Please provide the EXPLAIN.  Something less obvious is going wrong.

Comment: I've provided the EXPLAIN on above

Comment: 3.3 min with my INDEX?  How long without?  How many rows in the resultset?  What is the EXPLAIN _with_ my INDEX?